# why does datatable.Clear, clears the other datatable as well?

Tags: c#, .net

```
DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
dttemp=orderedTable;
dttemp.Rows.Clear();
```

for some reason the `orderedTable` is being cleared as well! does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: dttemp=orderedTable;
<=== that's why....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `dttemp` is now referencing `orderedTable` - they both point to the same location in memory.

This line of code:

```
dttemp = orderedTable;
```

does **not** do a full, deep copy! It just points `dttemp` to the same place that `orderedTable` lives at....

So if you clear the `.Rows()`, then those are gone regardless of whether you're lookign at it through `dttemp` or `orderedTable`.

If you want a real, full, deep copy, use this:

```
dttemp = orderedTable.Copy();   // copies structure and data
```

or

```
dttemp = orderedTable.Clone();  // copies the structure, but no data
```

Comment: yes, Copy() creates the deep copy, but the OP is clearing anyways, so you'd use Clone()

Answer (score 8):

By the time you've executed this line:

```
dttemp = orderedTable;
```

there's only actually one `DataTable` which is relevant. The `DataTable` you created in the first line of code is eligible for garbage collection - nothing's taking any notice of it. The line quoted here doesn't make a copy of the *object* - it makes a copy of the *reference*, so that `dttemp` and `orderedTable` refer to the same `DataTable`.

`DataTable` is a reference type. It's absolutely *vital* that you understand how reference types work in C# - otherwise the whole language will have baffling results for you. I have an [article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) which you may find useful along those lines.

To put your code into context, imagine that a `DataTable` is actually a house. You give your home address to two different people. One goes and paints the house red... and then the other visits the house. Obviously he'll find it's red.

The important thing is that you didn't give each person "your house" - you just gave them a way of *getting to* your house. That's how reference types work in C#.

The value of `dttemp` isn't a `DataTable` - it's a *reference* to a `DataTable`. Changes made to that object via any other variables will still be seen via `dttemp`.

Comment: well, presumably 2 tables - one from `orderedTable` and one from `new DataTable()` that is discarded ;p

Comment: @Marc: True. Hadn't noticed that bit :)

Comment: I made the same incorrect statement - I just edited it before anyone noticed ;p

Answer (score 4):

You have two variables (`dttemp` and `orderedTable`) which, at the time when you call `Clear()`, point at the same object. Thus a change to the **object** pointed to by `dttemp` is also a change to the **object** pointed to by `orderedTable`.

The table you create with `new DataTable()` is simply discarded onto the heap (waiting to be garbage-collected) when you assign `dttemp=orderedTable;`

Answer (score 0):

orderedTable is just holding a reference to the dttemp object hence when you change dttemp you are changing the data in memory which is the same object as referred by orderedTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
dttemp=orderedTable;
```

That line assigns `orderedTable` to `dttemp`. Making calls on `dttemp` will then by definition affect `orderedTable`.

Answer (score 0):

because it's a reference type and not a value type.

Answer (score 0):

In C# class variables are saved by reference, which means that the variable itself is something like a pointer to the real data. So the variables (except for primitives) don't really hold the data, but just point to the data you assign to it.

In your case, you point to an empty table :

```
DataTable dttemp = new DataTable();
```

but then you make it point to another table:

```
dttemp=orderedTable;
```

This effectively causes two things:

1. The variable `dttemp` now points to the `orderedTable`
2. The new table you created in the first line has nothing pointing at it. It's lost in the memory with no reference to it, and will be finalized when the Garbage Collector runs.